# Run myVBS Scheduled Task

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbs code that i would like to run via a scheduled task.  Say myVBS.vbs;  I have created another batch file where called my task as :
cscript.exe //nologon c:\myVBS.vbs
 Of course, nothing happened.  When i execute myVBS.vbs (via mouse or keyboard, enter command) it works fine.
I am open to any suggestion as to run this task but rather automatically and on timely scheduled.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try logging the `cscript` output, to find out what goes wrong:

> cscript.exe //Nologo
>   myVBS.vbs > "%TEMP%output.txt" 2>> "%TEMP%\errors.txt"

Plus mind the typo (`//nologo*n*`) in your question.